# I need an advanced windows store app RichEditBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

Is there something like ckedit for Windows store apps?
I have a text in a RichEditBox and I want to change the size of some words in it's text and make other words bold and after that be able to save the changes on the text and load it for the next time
is there a way to do this?